# How to add a new value to the dictionary, which will be the ratio of the previous two

Tags: python, dictionary

I have array of dictionaries with information

```
[
 {"id_1":1, "id_2":2, "item_price":50, "delivery_price":100}
 {"id_1":1, "id_2":3, "item_price":200, "delivery_price":100}
 {"id_1":1, "id_2":4, "item_price":60, "delivery_price":100}
]
```

How to add in every dict new element "item_cost" which will be the ratio of "item_price" to "delivery_price"?

I want to get this one

```
[
 {"id_1":1, "id_2":2, "item_price":50, "delivery_price":100, "item_cost":50/100}
 {"id_1":1, "id_2":3, "item_price":200, "delivery_price":100, "item_cost":200/100}
 {"id_1":1, "id_2":4, "item_price":60, "delivery_price":100,
"item_cost":60/100}
]
```

Comment: What's stopping you? See how to create a [mcve] and [edit] the question.

Comment: 1) Loop and get each dictionary in list. 2) Add `"item_cost"` key to the dictionary for current iteration with its value being the ratio you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like that:

```py
list_of_dict = [
 {"id_1":1, "id_2":2, "item_price":50, "delivery_price":100},
 {"id_1":1, "id_2":3, "item_price":200, "delivery_price":100},
 {"id_1":1, "id_2":4, "item_price":60, "delivery_price":100}
]

for elem in list_of_dict:
    elem['ratio'] = elem['item_price'] / elem['delivery_price']

print(list_of_dict)
```